# How do I calculate the minimum length my cell needs for my CSS minmax()?

Tags: css, css-grid, minmax

I'm trying to design some CSS Grids.

I want to set the MINIMUM length to the amount of space the top cell needs 
to keep all its text **in one line**.
For example:

```
<h2 id="dominantCell">This is some text</h2>
<style>
    #dominantCell {  /* I don't know how long the text is in one line */
       grid-template-columns: minmax( /* <h2>'s width */ , 100%)
    }    /* How do I find out what the min should be WITHOUT counting pixels? */
</style>
```

How do I reasonably calculate something like this without counting pixels every time?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. Can you post a code sample illustrating the problem?

Comment: @Michael_B I added a code sample to explain what I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grid-template-columns: minmax( min-content, 100% )
```

OR

```
grid-template-columns: minmax( min-content, 1fr )
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) for details about `min-content`.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I read the MDN, and just to be sure, I think it said `min-content`  sets the minimum to the value of the grid's largest item. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Would be best if you give it a try. Post a demo with the results. We can see where things stand.

Comment: Yeah, my tests worked out. And if it works how my tests did, I'll assume this is the answer I was looking for. Just wanted to confirm I knew what I was reading.